# What is the best way to run UPDATE with INNER JOIN on large tables in mysql?

Tags: mysql

I have a large table of 10M rows, let's call it table A.
I also have another table with the same structure exactly, and with 2M rows. Let's call it table B.

Each row contains about 20 fields (both textual and numeric).

I would like to update all rows in table A with values of appropriate rows in table B (joined by the primary key).

Trivial UPDATE runs several hours:

```
UPDATE A 
INNER JOIN B 
  ON A.primary_key=B.primary_key 
SET A.field1=B.field1, 
    A.field2=B.field2....;
```

Can you advice some smarter approach rather then one single UPDATE command on inner join?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: innodb or myisam ? if innodb start trans; update; commit; http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/commit.html

Comment: InnoDB.
Why "start trans; update; commit" makes the UPDATE faster?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are probably having buffer issues due to the size of the resultant dataset. You could try doing it in smaller chunks, maybe 100K rows at a time. You could do it based on the PK. Find the max primary_key in table A and then divide by 100,000 to get the number of iterations required.

```
// PSEUDO CODE
MAX = SELECT MAX(primary_key) FROM table A
NUM_PER_QUERY = 100000
NUM_ITERATIONS = CEIL(MAX/NUM_PER_QUERY)

for (i = 0; i < NUM_ITERATIONS; i++) {
    UPDATE .... WHERE A.primary_key BETWEEN ((i * NUM_PER_QUERY) + 1) AND ((i + 1) * NUM_PER_QUERY)
}
```

Comment: The problem with this approach is that it assumes that the primary keys are uniformly distributed. However, in my case this assumption can't be done.

Comment: It does not matter what the key distribution is. It means that each query will be for at most 100K rows which will need significantly less memory than trying to do the update in one go.